# Two concurrent authentications, managed separately, with Spring Security 3.1?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security

I am building an app that has two types of users:

- regular users (have role 'user')
- administrative users (have role 'admin', but do not have 'user' privileges)

How can I go about allowing someone to login/logout as a user and an administrator separately?

I have two realms defined using two http elements (I have two realms to allow separate login pages and user databases):

```
<security:http pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="adminAuthManager"
    entry-point-ref="adminLoginUrlAuthEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/admin/login" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/admin/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    ...
</security:http>
<security:http pattern="/**" authentication-manager-ref="userAuthManager"
    entry-point-ref="userLoginUrlAuthEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/settings" access="hasRole('user')" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    ...
</security:http>
```

With the current setup, I'm not able to allow a single session to be both an authenticated user and an authenticated administrator. When someone logs in as a user while logged in as an administrator, his/her administrator authentication is lost (or replaced) and vice versa.

I've thought about separating the two realms into two different webapps but would prefer not to, if possible.

EDIT: Here's an example of how I would like this to work:

1. Person navigates to the site, let's say at path / which is open to all users
2. Person clicks on login and authenticates at /login; person now has role "user"
3. Person decides to navigate to a /admin/* page and is presented with the /admin/login page
4. Person authenticates using another set of credentials at /admin/login; person now has roles "admin" AND "user"
5. From the server point of view, when user is on an /admin/** page, the user's principal is the username he used for /admin/login; when on a /** page, the user's principal is the username he used for /login
6. Person finishes admin activities and decides to log out of his admin session at /admin/logout; person loses "admin" role but is left with "user" role
7. Person finally decides to log out of user role as well and goes to path /logout; person is now anonymous

I'm hoping this can be achieved without writing too much custom functionality.

Comment: Hi andy. Maybe i'm missing something, but can't you handle the user roles from your authentication manager beans?

Comment: Hi Dani, thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure I follow. Can you explain in more detail? I've also edited my post to add a better example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, very explanatory. In my opinion, the best approach for points 1-5 would be have an user who has only user role and an admin who has both roles (I'm not really sure if this is what you need). For point 6 I think that you could manually remove the admin role from the collection of authorities, instead of doing the proper logout.

Comment: Your suggestion gives me some ideas. In the example, the person logs in as a user first, then admin. But I'd like the reverse case to work too, i.e. admin first, then user. Perhaps I could check at each login whether the person is already logged in as the other role and if so, apply the role to the new authentication. During logout, if the person has both roles, the server will automatically re-authenticate with only the role that the person has not logged out of. But this is getting a bit complex and may compromise security / compatibility with future spring-sec releases :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want the same person to have two sets of credentials? This scenario is typically implemented using step-up authentication i.e. the user is always the same but he is prompted to re-authenticate when trying to access an admin area of the app. For example you may prompt him to enter some additional information or authenticate using a two factor token.

In the past I have implemented this using a custom AccessDecisionManager/Voter which checks if the user is trying to access a "more secure" area of the site and then throws an [InsufficientAuthenticationException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/index.html) if he does not have the correct role. The entry point then handles this exception and prompts the user to re-authenticate and spring assigns the new roles

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you for the suggestion. I am essentially trying to combine what should perhaps be two different webapps into a single webapp. The user is not accessing a more secure area but a different area, e.g. you log into facebook and then log into twitter, but in the same domain (twitbook.com :P). The signup processes are different and the accounts are stored in different databases. Why they are in the same webapp is because they share a lot of similar views and logic. We didn't plan for concurrent logins but seems it might make life easier for users who have both types of accounts.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details about the custom AccessDecisionManager implementation? This may be the way to go, but instead of a two factor token, it would be an additional username/password. When retrieving the principal, the UserDetails can return a username based on the current requestURI (admin realm or user realm).

Comment: Ok so in your case the AccessDecisionVoter would check the Authentication object and the Secured Object - in your case the secured object argument to the vote() method would be a FilterInvocation, i.e. a web request. You would then know the who (authentication) and the what (FilterInvocation) and so you should be able to decide whether the user needs to log in again. You could further enhance this pattern by creating your own config attributes for the voter but this should at least give you an idea of the pattern. Check out the AccessDecisionVoter in the spring docs for more info